# Simplest/shortest/cheapest way to send a signal from service to activity

Tags: android, service, signals, broadcast

I have a music player with a MusicService that runs the player and notification, and a Player activity for UI. I want the `Player` to react to very simple signals sent by the `MusicService`, like "song ended", or react to notification button presses.

The way I've done this is via Broadcasts in the service:

```
            mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(filename));
            mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("MyXVFPlayer-SongFinished"));
            });
```

and then in `Player`:

```
private class DataUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals("MyXVFPlayer-SongFinished")) {
                nextsong();
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, but then I've read that Broadcasts are overkill for this. Better a LocalBroadcast. But now it is deprecated. So LiveData. But maybe a Messenger. Or an EventBus. Or a service as a singleton. Or...??

So I am very confused now. I have no idea which is the cheapest (less resource intensive) way. In September 2021, that is...

Any advice?

Comment: Even though LocalBroadcast is deprecated, it is not because it is obsolete, but rather because the pattern is kind of throwned upon. I would say it is still practical and convenient in many cases where the "layer violation" is not a concern. If you are worried about the "deprecated' label, use a normal broadcast with the package set.

Comment: Didn't know about the possibility of setting the package. Is this somehow equivalent to a LocalBroadcast?

Comment: In a way, yes. It means that only that package will receive the broadcast, but I suspect that it still be much heaviear on resource use than LocalBroadcast. I think it shouldn't matter in your case - the sound track will not finish every millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way that is not deprecated: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). You may listen for changes using [registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener))

Comment: Nice "hack"... :)